# Performing multiple commits in one MongoDb connection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise

I am attempting to write a JavaScript application that will run locally on Node.js. I want to then have user input commands that will insert, update, or delete data from a MongoDb connection.

In other words, I would like the MongoDb connection to remain open while node.js is running so that a user's commands will do what it intends to do.

I have attempted to use multiple connections, but that doesn't seem to work with the promise stack. The user will insert an object, but if they then attempt to delete that object afterward, nothing will happen.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = require('./mongoConnection.json'); // this is my connection information
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri.connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoClient.connect(function(err, db){
    var dbo = db.db("TestBotDb").collection("Test");
    dbo.insertOne({ "data1" : "new data", "data2" : "new data2" });    

    var result = dbo.findOne({ "data2" : "new data2" });
    dbo.deleteOne({ "_id" : result._id});

});
```

Since it seems like inserts don't happen immediately, I don't know how I can break this out into functions later. I don't want to have to wait for an insert when the application is running in order to attempt to delete an object. I don't know necessarily when the user will insert vs when they will attempt to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async / await to do this.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = require('./mongoConnection.json'); // this is my connection information
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri.connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoClient.connect(async (err, db) =>{
    var dbo = db.db("TestBotDb").collection("Test");
    await dbo.insertOne({ "data1" : "new data", "data2" : "new data2" }); // Waits until your data insert or error

    var result = await dbo.findOne({ "data2" : "new data2" }); // Waits until read data or error
    await dbo.deleteOne({ "_id" : result._id}); // // Waits until delete data or error

});
```

Comment: Does "await" not continue the script until the promise is completed?